# Android IntentReceiver leaking

Tags: java, android

In my Android app, I have an Activity MainActivity which has a Fragment MainFragment which launches an IntentService and then transitions to Activity SelectPlayersActivity (which has a Fragment SelectPlayersFragment).  The IntentService may finish when either Activity is in the foreground.  So I must register BroadcastReceivers in both their fragments.  I do this by creating subclasses extending BroadcastReceiver in both Fragments named "NewGameServiceReceiver".  In both fragments, I register the BroadcastReiceiver as follows:

```
private void registerBroadcastReceivers() {
    IntentFilter newGameFilter = new IntentFilter(BroadcastReceivers.NEW_GAME_BROADCAST_RECEIVER.getName());
    newGameServiceReceiver = new NewGameServiceReceiver();
    getActivity().registerReceiver(newGameServiceReceiver, newGameFilter);

}
```

This is triggered in the onStart() method in both fragments:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    registerBroadcastReceivers();
}
```

Both fragments I unregister as follows:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(newGameServiceReceiver);
}
```

However, when I evantually transition off to a third Activity, DDMS reports a memory leak on NewGameServiceReceiver.  The unregisterReceiver() methods get called when they should be.

```
07-31 00:01:30.017: E/ActivityThread(2002): Activity
ws.hamacher.cluebuddy.SelectPlayersActivity has leaked IntentReceiver
ws.hamacher.cluebuddy.SelectPlayersFragment$NewGameServiceReceiver@b3822ea0
that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to
unregisterReceiver()? 07-31 00:01:30.017: E/ActivityThread(2002):
android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity
ws.hamacher.cluebuddy.SelectPlayersActivity has leaked IntentReceiver
ws.hamacher.cluebuddy.SelectPlayersFragment$NewGameServiceReceiver@b3822ea0
that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to
unregisterReceiver()?
```

Is this a proper way to declare and handle `BroadcastReceviers`?  Notice that I have given the `IntentFilters` in both fragments the same constructor argument `(BroadcastReceivers.NEW_GAME_BROADCAST_RECEIVER.getName())`.  This is necessary because I don't know which Fragment will receive the service's Intent.

Any comments/help are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try first un-registering the receiver and then calling `super.onPause()`

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(newGameServiceReceiver);
    super.onPause();

}
```

Hope this helps.